# Which vulnerability scanner is correct?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners

We use latest ose-cli from RedHat official repository, which claims there are no security issues and rating is "A: This image does not contain known unapplied security advisories.":

https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/openshift4/ose-cli/5cd9ba3f5a13467289f4d51d?tag=v4.13.0-202307172043.p0.g8b4d4ed.assembly.stream&push_date=1690420198000&container-tabs=security

However, our security scanner tenable.io claims following vulnerabilities are present on OS level:

```
Found 38 CVEs:
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -               CVE - Score - Package
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2023-1667 -   6.5 - libssh:0.9.6
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2023-1667 -   6.5 - libssh-config:0.9.6
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2021-25220 -   6.8 - python3-bind:9.11.36
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2021-25220 -   6.8 - bind-utils:9.11.36
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2021-25220 -   6.8 - bind-libs:9.11.36
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2021-25220 -   6.8 - bind-libs-lite:9.11.36
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2021-25220 -   6.8 - bind-license:9.11.36
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-48303 -   5.5 - tar:1.30
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2023-27535 -   5.9 - libcurl:7.61.1
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2023-27535 -   5.9 - curl:7.61.1
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-40304 -   7.8 - libxml2:2.9.7
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-40304 -   7.8 - python3-libxml2:2.9.7
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-47629 -   9.8 - libksba:1.3.5
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2023-0361 -   7.4 - gnutls:3.6.16
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-37434 -   9.8 - rsync:3.1.3
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2022-3821 -   5.5 - systemd:239
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2022-3821 -   5.5 - systemd-libs:239
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2022-3821 -   5.5 - systemd-pam:239
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2023-23916 -   6.5 - libcurl:7.61.1
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2023-23916 -   6.5 - curl:7.61.1
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-45061 -   7.5 - platform-python:3.6.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-45061 -   7.5 - python3-libs:3.6.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2021-46848 -   9.1 - libtasn1:4.13
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-43680 -   7.5 - expat:2.2.5
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2023-0215 -   7.5 - openssl:1.1.1k
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2023-0215 -   7.5 - openssl-libs:1.1.1k
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2022-1304 -   7.8 - libcom_err:1.45.6
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2021-28861 -   7.4 - platform-python:3.6.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2021-28861 -   7.4 - python3-libs:3.6.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2022-4304 -   5.9 - openssl:1.1.1k
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2022-4304 -   5.9 - openssl-libs:1.1.1k
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2020-10735 -   7.5 - platform-python:3.6.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2020-10735 -   7.5 - python3-libs:3.6.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-40897 -   5.9 - python3-setuptools:39.2.0
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-40897 -   5.9 - python3-setuptools-wheel:39.2.0
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-40897 -   5.9 - platform-python-setuptools:39.2.0
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2016-3709 -   6.1 - libxml2:2.9.7
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2016-3709 -   6.1 - python3-libxml2:2.9.7
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-42898 -   8.8 - krb5-libs:1.18.2
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2022-4415 -   5.5 - systemd:239
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2022-4415 -   5.5 - systemd-libs:239
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2022-4415 -   5.5 - systemd-pam:239
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2022-4450 -   7.5 - openssl:1.1.1k
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2022-4450 -   7.5 - openssl-libs:1.1.1k
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-43552 -   5.9 - libcurl:7.61.1
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-43552 -   5.9 - curl:7.61.1
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2023-26604 -   7.8 - systemd:239
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2023-26604 -   7.8 - systemd-libs:239
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2023-26604 -   7.8 - systemd-pam:239
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2022-2795 -   5.3 - python3-bind:9.11.36
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2022-2795 -   5.3 - bind-utils:9.11.36
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2022-2795 -   5.3 - bind-libs:9.11.36
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2022-2795 -   5.3 - bind-libs-lite:9.11.36
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2022-2795 -   5.3 - bind-license:9.11.36
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-35252 -   3.7 - libcurl:7.61.1
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-35252 -   3.7 - curl:7.61.1
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2023-2283 -   6.5 - libssh:0.9.6
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2023-2283 -   6.5 - libssh-config:0.9.6
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2020-24736 -   5.5 - sqlite-libs:3.26.0
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2023-24329 -   7.5 - platform-python:3.6.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2023-24329 -   7.5 - python3-libs:3.6.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2023-2828 -   7.5 - python3-bind:9.11.36
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2023-2828 -   7.5 - bind-utils:9.11.36
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2023-2828 -   7.5 - bind-libs:9.11.36
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2023-2828 -   7.5 - bind-libs-lite:9.11.36
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2023-2828 -   7.5 - bind-license:9.11.36
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2023-0286 -   7.4 - openssl:1.1.1k
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -     CVE-2023-0286 -   7.4 - openssl-libs:1.1.1k
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-40303 -   7.5 - libxml2:2.9.7
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-40303 -   7.5 - python3-libxml2:2.9.7
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-42010 -   6.5 - dbus-tools:1.12.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-42010 -   6.5 - dbus-common:1.12.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-42010 -   6.5 - dbus-libs:1.12.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-42010 -   6.5 - dbus-daemon:1.12.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-42010 -   6.5 - dbus:1.12.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-35737 -   7.5 - sqlite-libs:3.26.0
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-42012 -   6.5 - dbus-tools:1.12.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-42012 -   6.5 - dbus-common:1.12.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-42012 -   6.5 - dbus-libs:1.12.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-42012 -   6.5 - dbus-daemon:1.12.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-42012 -   6.5 - dbus:1.12.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-42011 -   6.5 - dbus-tools:1.12.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-42011 -   6.5 - dbus-common:1.12.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-42011 -   6.5 - dbus-libs:1.12.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-42011 -   6.5 - dbus-daemon:1.12.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-42011 -   6.5 - dbus:1.12.8
16:24:47 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m -    CVE-2022-36227 -   9.8 - libarchive:3.3.3
```

Another scanner (trivy) says there aren't any OS-level vulnerabilities (same as the RedHat tool).

We are confused: what scanner should we trust? RedHat, trivy or tenable.io?

Comment: Why is it showing `ERROR`? Did you check to see if those package versions are the ones installed? For instance, if you have libssh:0.9.6, then there is that CVE associated with it. https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-1667 So, the investigation is simple: if there is that package, then there is a problem. That's how you verify. Automated scanners often need their results manually checked. False positives and negatives are common.

Comment: Red Hat generally backports security fixes rather than upgrading tools "for stability."  So scanners which look at just the version installed often see an "old" version number and react to that.  Presumably Red Hat's own scanner is smart enough to know which security fixes have been backported and so which versions are considered up-to-date.

Comment: You should put your comment as the answer @gowenfawr as it's spot on

Comment: @gowenfawr is correct. Some official reading:  https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting 
You can also check where a particular CVE your scanner is reporting was addressed by modifying the URL or well using search: e.g. https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2023-1667